# Excel Ribbon customisation: Dynamic menu, getContent and OnAction

Tags: xml, vba, excel, ribbon

The code below produces the following error, caused by the OnAction part: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

```
Sub GetContent(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
Dim xml As String
Dim i As Integer
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Row

xml = "<menu xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">"

For i = 2 To lastRow
    xml = xml & "<button id=" & """but" & i & """" & " label=""" & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value & """" & " onAction=" & """" &     ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value & """" & " />"
Next

xml = xml & "</menu>"

returnedVal = xml
End Sub
```

The goal is to create a dynamic menu in the ribbon based on input in two columns in a worksheet, one with table name (A) and one with macro name (B).

Comment: What does the data in column B in ActiveSheet look like? You are using data in column B as callback methods for the menu onAction events - if the code for these methods is missing or has the wrong signature you could get the error you mention.

Comment: Table1
Table2
Table3 - each in its own cell

Comment: The output looks completely valid... <menu xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"><button id="but2" label="Tabel 1" onAction="Table1" /><button id="but3" label="Tabel 2" onAction="Table2" /><button id="but4" label="Tabel 3" onAction="Table3" /></menu>

Comment: Don't you have too many quotes after `onAction`? Should it be 3 quotes between the 2 `&` after `onAction`?

Comment: How do the signatures for the Table1, Table2 and Table3 callbacks in the VBA code look? In what code module are they?

Comment: Zac: As you can see above in the comment "The output looks completely valid...", the onAction="Table3" has the correct amount of quotations.

Comment: Olle: I don't know what 'signatures' mean. The code above is in a regular module. The Sub is called by the xml embedded in the file (which works when I leave out the OnAction part). I embedded it with the application 'Custom UI Editor For Microsoft Office'

Comment: Olle: Here is the xml-part, which handles the dynamic menu, taken from the UI Editor: <dynamicMenu id="dynamicMenu1" 
                     label="Tabeller" 
   size="large"
imageMso="ForecastInsert" 
                     getContent="GetContent" />

Comment: OK! By signature I meant what the subs in the code are called and what arguments they expect, and by your answer I can see that's exactly where the problem was! :)

Comment: Great Olle. Throw an answer if you want and I'll appoint you the checkmark :).

Comment: That's ok, I'll give your answer a vote instead, since you solved it yourself!

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution. I needed the following in the macros I was trying to execute with the onAction statements:

`ByRef control As IRibbonControl`

so:

```
Sub Table1(ByRef control As IRibbonControl)
code
end sub
```